# redirect GET requests for absolute paths of a particular domain to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, localhost, absolute-path

I have added some absolute paths in html, ie GET requests to other domains.

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/dir/file.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.sample.com/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/all/home/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
```

How to redirect all requests to example.com to localhost, 127 0 0 1
that is
http://www.example.com/ should get redirected to localhost/

no other requests should be affected

The following code works for redirecting path starting with dir/ , but does not work when I use absolute domain name http://www.example.com/ instead of dir to link the file

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)$   http://localhost/dev/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/http://localhost/dev/.*
```

How to do this using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You'd want something like this in your www.example.com's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: i own example.com and can edit htaccess, but doing that will not allow  people to use my website as requests will be redirected to localhost and resources will not load. i want to do this to test my website that contains absolute paths inside localhost. can something be done ? i just want to locally test my site that too offline without changing the absolute path's domain name, ie i dont want to change example.com to 127.0.0.1 in source code to test it.

Comment: @ShubhamBadal not using htaccess, the htaccess file won't do anything unless you go explicitly to the `example.com` site. You may be able to crate a host record on your computer to point `example.com` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: ya i guess you are ryt, bcz the html sends request to website and localhost is powerless, and ya i tried adding it to hosts in sys32 by writing 127.0.0.1 www.example.com but then i was unable to access my website. i dont want whole website to be redirected.